# HP wireless mouse stopped working on Mint 20.1

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-mint

I'm on Mint 20.1 Xfce and recently my HP wireless mouse stopped working despite being shown as detected in `hwinfo --mouse`.

- Works fine on a different Windows laptop.
- Replacing battery with a brand new one doesn't work.
- Borrowed a wired USB mouse - that works fine.
- Changed USB port - no difference.

Output of `hwinfo --mouse`

```bash
24: USB 00.0: 10503 USB Mouse
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: cLrx.x7nP4cBNWk7
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-2:1.0
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "HP Wireless Mouse 220"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x03f0 "HP"
  Device: usb 0x2141 "HP Wireless Mouse 220"
  Revision: "1.12"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0025
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse0)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse0, /dev/input/event5
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:32)
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v03F0p2141d0112dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 5
    Wheels: 2
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #26 (Hub)

31: PS/2 00.0: 10500 PS/2 Mouse
  [Created at input.249]
  Unique ID: AH6Q.ZHI3OT7LsxA
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
  Vendor: 0x0002 
  Device: 0x0007 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0002
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse1)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse1, /dev/input/event6
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:33)
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 2
    Wheels: 0
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

33: PS/2 00.0: 10500 PS/2 Mouse
  [Created at input.249]
  Unique ID: AH6Q.Q2ZgYWg_7V2
  Hardware Class: mouse
  Model: "Mouseemu virtual mouse"
  Vendor: 0x001f 
  Device: 0x001e "Mouseemu virtual mouse"
  Compatible to: int 0x0210 0x0025
  Device File: /dev/input/mice (/dev/input/mouse2)
  Device Files: /dev/input/mice, /dev/input/mouse2, /dev/input/event18
  Device Number: char 13:63 (char 13:34)
  Driver Info #0:
    Buttons: 5
    Wheels: 2
    XFree86 Protocol: explorerps/2
    GPM Protocol: exps2
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i mouse`

```bash
[    0.510128] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.871469] Modules linked in: i915(+) i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt crc32_pclmul ahci fb_sys_fops libahci i2c_i801 psmouse r8169 drm lpc_ich mii wmi i2c_hid video hid
[    0.969438] usb 1-2: Product: HP Wireless Mouse 220 
[    1.505236] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5652], y [..4846]
[    1.534740] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1330..], y [1094..]
[    1.534746] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN1efb SYN1e00 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    1.584312] input: HP HP Wireless Mouse 220  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:03F0:2141.0001/input/input7
[    1.584522] hid-generic 0003:03F0:2141.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [HP HP Wireless Mouse 220 ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[    1.594119] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xf00123/0x840300/0x2e800/0x0, board id: 3127, fw id: 8526786
[  112.701071] input: Mouseemu virtual keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input18
[  112.701576] input: Mouseemu virtual mouse as /devices/virtual/input/input19
[  345.523277] usb 1-1: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[  345.526762] input: PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:093A:2510.0002/input/input20
[  345.526894] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 3864.575462] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5652], y [..4846]
[ 3864.611623] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1330..], y [1094..]
[ 5830.326713] usb 1-2: Product: HP Wireless Mouse 220 
[ 5830.329909] input: HP HP Wireless Mouse 220  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:03F0:2141.0003/input/input21
[ 5830.330474] hid-generic 0003:03F0:2141.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [HP HP Wireless Mouse 220 ] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
```

Output of `inxi -Fxz`

```bash
System:    Kernel: 4.15.0-109-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 
           Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 80C1 v: 96.31 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde v: F.11 date: 07/23/2015 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 35.6 Wh condition: 36.0/41.6 Wh (87%) model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 status: Charging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-5200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 17559 
           Speed: 828 MHz min/max: 500/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1382 2: 1683 3: 1650 4: 1610 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-109-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 
           bus ID: 07:00.0 
           IF: enp7s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtl8723be v: kernel 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 0d:00.0 
           IF: wlp13s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 260.73 GiB (56.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050A7E680 size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 453.26 GiB used: 189.38 GiB (41.8%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: /home size: 453.26 GiB used: 189.38 GiB (41.8%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 12.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 254 Uptime: 2h 13m Memory: 11.64 GiB used: 2.44 GiB (21.0%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 clang: 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

What else can I try?